# Pushing multiple magento products / static blocks live simulatenously

Tags: php, magento

I have a customer who has a drop-ship type of Magento site, new products go live every month - I need to figure out a way to make all the products ideally go live at once, as well as the changes to all the pages.

Many of the pages that display a list of category products reference static blocks, whose content also needs to change..

**an example:**

```
{{block type="cms/block" block_id="category-art-october-2013"}} 
{{block type="catalog/product_list" category_id="41" template="catalog/product/list.phtml"}}
{{block type="cms/block" block_id="coming-soon-art-october-2013"}}
```

Is it the best way / possible to have some kind of variable in the static block, so that I can change some sort of date/identifier and have it load in the correct month of products?

Answer (score 1):

instead of using `{{block type="cms/block" block_id="category-art-october-2013"}} {{block type="catalog/product_list" category_id="41" template="catalog/product/list.phtml"}} {{block type="cms/block" block_id="coming-soon-art-october-2013"}}`

you can try doing this via the xml layout updates, which would allow you to use "Custom Designs" with "from" and "to" dates.
under `Layout Update XML` from your cms pages, you can try something like this

```
<reference name="content">
    <block type="cms/block" name="art-october">
        <action method="setBlockId"><block_id>category-art-october-2013</block_id></action>     
    </block>
    <block type="catalog/product_list" name="list_category" template="catalog/product/list.phtml">
        <action name="setCategoryId">41</action>
    </block>
    <block type="cms/block" name="art-comming-soon">
        <action method="setBlockId"><block_id>coming-soon-art-october-2013</block_id></action>      
    </block>
</reference>
```

and the prepare the configuration for the next month under "Custom Design" and adjust the xml to you needs.

hope that helps